# why my react native dotenv is not working?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use react-native-dotenv but its not working.

https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv

I created a .env file and added a FB_ID=21221

then I go to babel and edited like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'react-native-dotenv'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

I restarted it and want to access FB_ID but its not exists

Answer (score 2):

react-native-dotenv maintainer. This is an old version of the documentation. The new documentation is on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv). This library is now a plugin not a preset. try `plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin', 'module:react-native-dotenv']`. Also, the `api.cache(true)` doesn't help. Try `api.cache(false)` instead.